# Difference between- Kotlin DSL vs Groovy DSL vs Kotlin SDL+Gradle ? in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio

I just update my Android Studio after a long time. There are three options and *Kotlin DSL* with recommended quote.

I always code in Java only. So any changes come if I select in Kotlin. Because I never use Kotlin, and their first Activity class come with Kotlin.

[image]

I do not know Groovy/Kotlin language. In future, I want to add any SDK all of their documentations will be in maybe Groovy, then I will face difficulty to add that in Kotlin DSL or not?

Comment: Have a read at this https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2023/04/kotlin-dsl-is-the-default-for-new-gradle-builds/

Comment: Fundamentally, the Groovy DSL is the same as the Kotlin DSL, except the former is written in Groovy, and the latter is written in Kotlin. Though the Kotlin DSL gives better IDE editing support (because Kotlin is strongly and statically typed). Your actual project can still be in Java if you use the Kotlin DSL.

Comment: Version catalogs seem to be a relatively new (and apparently still experimental?) feature (independent of Groovy DSL vs Kotlin DSL). See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html

Comment: Not sure I understand your edit. The language used to write the settings/build files is separate from the language used by the actual project.

Comment: @slaw Edit mean for Example If i want to add FacebookAudienceNetwork sdk then there all documentations will be old - documentation say: add this code in BuildGradle-Project ,that time Convert that code in kotlin maybe difficult.

Comment: Ideally, non-dead projects would have documentation for both the Kotlin DSL and the Groovy DSL by now. But Gradle does provide a [Kotlin DSL Primer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) and [migration guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_groovy_to_kotlin_dsl.html#migrating_groovy_kotlin) if you need help translating. There's also [Android's migration guide](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-kotlin-dsl). And it would help to have at least a rudimentary understanding of the [Kotlin language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/home.html).

Comment: All that said, if you're more comfortable using the Groovy DSL, I'd say go ahead and use it. There are not, as far as I know, plans to deprecate it.

Answer (score 1):

It is a choice related to `build.gradle` management.

**What is DSL**

> A DSL is a computer language designed for a specific problem domain.
> It is created to address the needs of a particular industry or
> application. For example, a DSL for statistical analysis might include
> features that make it easy to write and manipulate data sets. A DSL
> for music composition might include features for writing and arranging
> notes and chords.
>
> **DSLs are not general-purpose programming languages**. They are designed
> to be used in a specific domain and provide a more natural and
> intuitive way to write code in that domain. DSLs can be embedded in
> general-purpose programming languages, or they can be stand-alone
> languages.

**Kotlin DSL**

You use kotlin dsl in build gradle management. It is equivalent to using Kotlin programming language.

> Kotlin DSLs are DSLs that are written in the Kotlin programming
> language. They allow developers to create a language that is specific
> to their problem domain quickly and easily.

**Groovy DSL**

You use groovy dsl in build gradle management. It is equivalent to using Groovy programming language.

> The Groovy DSL is a wrapper and extension to Java DSL. The main goal
> we pursue here is to make Spring Integration development on Groovy as
> smooth and straightforward as is it possible with interoperability
> with existing Java DSL and some Groovy extensions or language-specific
> structures.

Answer (score 1):

**Kotlin DSL**: You write your gradle build files in a kotlin dsl and therefore you can use kotlin: see this [primer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html)

**Kotlin DSL + Version Catalogs**: You still write your gradle build files in kotlin dsl, but the dependency versions are kept in a version catalog file. This helps to share version codes, see this [site](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html)

**Groovy DSL**: The "old" way of writing gradle build files, here the dsl is written in groovy and you can write groovy code.

To answer your question, you can choose any of them and you can add any dependency, no matter what they are using.

The gradle documentation also provides the option to see sample code in either kotlin or groovy:
[image]